# $X_n \xrightarrow{law} X \iff \forall x \in \mathbb{Z}^d, \mathbb{P}[X_n = x] \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}[X = x] $

Tags: random-variables, weak-convergence

If $X_n, X \in \mathbb{Z}^d$, then

$X_n \xrightarrow{law} X \iff \forall x \in \mathbb{Z}^d, \mathbb{P}[X_n = x] \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}[X = x] $.

One way ($\implies$):

Assume $X_n \xrightarrow{law} X$ by definition $\mathbb{P}_{X_n} \xrightarrow{weakly} \mathbb{P}_X$ or equivalently $\forall \Phi$ continuous with a compact support we have that:

$\mathbb{E}[\Phi(X_n)] \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[\Phi (X)]$.

How could I choose $\Phi$ s.t. I can derive the other part. I thought of the following:

If I choose $\Phi$ as $1_{\{X = x\}}$ then I could derive the result but this would be just continuous a.e.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I suppose (but maybe someone can correct) that you do not want to continuity with respect to the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$ but rather those induced by the metric $d(x,y) = \delta_{(x,y)}$ on $\mathbb{Z}^d.$ With respect to this metric, then your given $\Phi$ is continuos, and you can apply the portmanteu lemma.

Comment: $x \mapsto 1_{x=z}$ is continuous

Comment: $ A \subset \Bbb{Z}^d$ is compact iff $\#A<\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to remember is that $X_n \stackrel{D}{\to} X$ if and only if $F_{X_n}(x) \to F_X(x)$ at all points $x$ which are continuity points of $F$. In your setting, you can write $P(X_n = x)$ and $P(X=x)$ as certain linear combinations of $F_{X_n}$ and $F_X$ evaluated at points near $x$ (e.g., for $X\in \mathbb{Z}$ $P(X=1) = P(X\le 1.5 ) - P(X\le 0.5)$), and at these points $F_X$ is continuous. This basic argument will work backwards and forwards to show both implications you need.